# Factory Boy set relation value with "model__key"

Tags: django, testing, fixtures, factory-boy

I'm trying to create some data with Factory Boy but I'm having problems using `model__key` like in the [OrderFactory example of the Factory Boy index page](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

This are my factories:

```
class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'auth.User'
        django_get_or_create = ('username',)

    username = 'user'


class EntityFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'app.Entity'

    user = SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

And this is what I'm trying run:

```
EntityFactory(user__username='admin')
```

But I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'user__username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Injecting the actual instance works:

```
admin = UserFactory(username='admin')
EntityFactory(user=admin)
```

Thanks!